# Rotate the String using Closure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Objective of the code is to rotate the string whenever the buton is clicked.
For eg.. If the input String is STACKOVERFLOW
After a click it becomes WSTACKOVERFLO
After next click it becomes OWSTACKOVERFL
and so on...
I want to solve it using Closure in javascript only.

```
<html>
<script>
var executeMe = function() {
  var word=document.getElementById("word").value;
  function(){
       word=word.slice(-1)+word.slice(0,-1);
     return word;
   }
 }();

function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = executeMe();
}
</script>
<body>
<p>Rotate the String.</p>
<input type="string" name="word" id="word"></input>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Rotate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have a function inside your function ?

Answer (score 1):

You were using a function inside a function.

You can use a simplified code like below using only one function

```js
const wordDom = document.getElementById("word");

function rotate() {
  let word = wordDom.value;
  word = word.slice(-1) + word.slice(0, -1);
  wordDom.value = word;
  return word;
}
```

```html
<p>Rotate the String.</p>
<input type="string" name="word" id="word">
<button type="button" onclick="rotate()">Rotate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but you guys are taken a global variable.<br/>
Please refer this... [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_counter3)<br/>
In the above given link you will find no such global variable

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
var rotateWord = null;
function changeValue(){
rotateWord=document.getElementById("word").value;
}
function executeMe () {
  function get(){
       rotateWord=rotateWord.slice(-1)+rotateWord.slice(0,-1);
   }
   get();
   return rotateWord;
 };

function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = executeMe();
}
</script>
<body>
<p>Rotate the String.</p>
<input type="string" name="word" id="word" onkeyup='changeValue()'></input>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Rotate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

store the input value in another variable and then change .

Comment: Thanks for the response but you guys are taken a global variable.<br/>
Please refer this... [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_counter3)<br/>
In the above given link you will find no such global variable

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following solution to rotate the string using Closure in JavaScript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
var rotateWord = null;
function changeValue(){
rotateWord=document.getElementById("word").value;
}
function executeMe () {
function get(){
   rotateWord=rotateWord.slice(-1)+rotateWord.slice(0,-1);
}
get();
return rotateWord;
};

function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = executeMe();
}
</script>
<body>
<p>Rotate the String.</p>
<input type="string" name="word" id="word" onkeyup='changeValue()'></input>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Rotate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```